# Clipboard data set as CF_TEXT can't be retrieved correctly as CF_UNICODETEXT

Tags: windows, unicode, character-encoding, internationalization, clipboard

Our app has a bug in the non-unicode version; if we copy some Russian characters to the clipboard(using SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT)), and then paste them into notepad, they don't get pasted as the Russian characters but as the code page 1252 equivalents (e.g. Э becomes Ý).

In trying to figure it out I made a little test app for pasting and it worked fine if I used GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT). if i use GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT) however, it has exactly the same issue as notepad.

So I assume that notepad is just using CF_UNICODETEXT on the paste. According to the MS documentation I've read, the clipboard is supposed to be able to convert CF_TEXT to CF_UNICODE text. In fact on the page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649013.aspx#_win32_Synthesized_Clipboard_Formats

it says "there is no advantage to placing the conversion format(s) on the clipboard."

If that is true then i must (I hope) be making a simple mistake that is easily corrected.

Can anyone help me out with a solution for this problem? 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably missing the `CF_LOCALE` for Russian? `CF_TEXT` is interpreted using the system locale, unless specified otherwise. If your system locale charset is CP1252, but your app locale is CP1251, windows will mis-guess when it converts your 8 bits text to Unicode.

Comment: OK Thank you, I think that might be all the information i need, but just to be clear before i report that i can't fix the bug then.  If the input language on the computer is set to Russian before the copy, then it does work correctly. But from what you say and what i find on MSDN when i look up CF_LOCALE, is that it has to use the input language to get a proper translation. I can't set it using CF_LOCALE because we don't know what language it might be in, so we will just have to tell our users that the input language must be set correctly. Does that sound right, or have I misunderstood? thanks

Comment: Convert the string to Unicode yourself according to code page 1241 or whatever code page the string is in. The put the Unicode string on the clipboard.

Comment: Eh, doesn't sound right at all. When *you* copy 8 bit text to the clipboard, then you should know what code page *your* text is in. How do you know 0xC7 is a `Э` ? That's only because you know the text is in CP1251.

Comment: it's user entered data.  They set their keyboard input language to Russian (or whatever language they want) and type away.  In out code we have no way to detect that that text was written in Russian after the  fact.

Comment: Eh, that's not right. You most certainly do. Remember, Windows uses Unicode internally. The Russian keyboard input is handled internally as Unicode. `Э` starts out as `U+0417`. Had you made a proper Unicode app, you'd have no translation whatsoever. But your app is 8 bits, so _its_ locale determines what happens to `Э`.

Comment: We have both a Unicode version and a non-unicode version for reasons decided at a much higher level than I'm at.  So yes the Unicode version works fine, this bug was reported on the non-unicode version, which means that the user will have to have the input language set correctly.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @John: In that case, don't bother. Just tell "international" users to use the Unicode variant, and rename the other to "english only".

Comment: I wish I had that choice but I don't. It's no problem though I really just needed some evidence to back me up when I tell them that  the input language must be set.  Now I understand it a lot better and have my back up so it's good now.  Thanks for your help.